# setting range and getting runtime error 9

Tags: excel, vba

I am completely stumped, as far as I can tell I am only calling variables that I have already coded, when I debug it highlights Set Rng

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim Prompt As String
    Dim RetValue As String
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim RowCrnt As Long

    Promt = ""
    With Sheets("Bin7in")
    Do While True

    RetValue = InputBox(Prompt & "Enter Die Number")
    If RetValue = "" Then
    Exit Do
    End If

    Set Rng = .Columns("C:C").Find(What:=RetValue, After:=.Range("C1"), _
    LookIn:=x1Formulas, LookAt:=x1Whole, SearchOrder:=x1ByRows, _
    SearchDirection:=x1Next, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    If Rng Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox RetValue & "Not found"
    Else
    Bin = Rng.Columns("A:A")
    MsgBox RetValue & "In Bin" & Bin
    End If
    Prompt = Prompt
    Loop
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: `x1Formulas` - all these need to be `xl`, not `x1`. The letter "L" not the number 1.

Comment: Rule 1 when programming VBA: Use **Option Explicit**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### A VBA Lookup Using the Find Method

**About the Error**

- The error `Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range` often occurs when a worksheet is not found.
- This code is located in a sheet module of the workbook containing this code (`ThisWorkbook`).
- When you click the command button, the active workbook (`ActiveWorkbook`) is `ThisWorkbook` and your code works 'fine'.
- When running the code from the Visual Basic Editor, another workbook could be active i.e. `ActiveWorkbook` is not `ThisWorkbook`, so if there is no `Bin7in` worksheet in it, the error will occur.
- Even worse, if there is a `Bin7in` worksheet in it, you could cause severe damage to it. In this case, you could 'only' receive the wrong information though.
- To avoid this, it is good practice to always explicitly specify each object (workbook, worksheet, range...), in this case, you could use `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Bin7in")` instead of the unqualified  ('tied' to the `ActiveWorkbook`) `Sheets("Bin7in")` in the *With statement*.

**A Quick Fix**

```vb
' Use 'Option Explicit' at beginning of each module.
' It forces you to declare (almost) all variables
' (arrays can be declared with 'ReDim').
' If you would have used it, the code would have, in sequential order,
' highlighted the following words:
' 'Promt', 'x1Formulas', 'x1Whole', 'x1ByRows', 'x1Next', and 'Bin'
' all with the message alert 'Compile Error: Variable not defined'
Option Explicit

' Indenting the code properly will make the code more readable 
' and help identify errors more easily.

Private CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim Prompt As String ' means 'Dim Prompt As String: Prompt = ""'
    Dim RetValue As String ' means 'Dim RetValue As String: RetValue = ""'
    ' Nitpicking here, but the Find method returns a reference to a single cell.
    Dim cell As Range ' means 'Dim cell As Range: Set cell = Nothing'
    Dim RowCrnt As Long ' means 'Dim RowCrnt As Long: RowCrnt = 0'
    Dim Bin As String ' means 'Dim Bin As String: Bin = ""'
    
    ' Promt = "" ' that's a typo
    ' Prompt = "" ' is redundant; it's already ""
    
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Bin7in")
        
        Do ' not sure what 'While True' is all about
            
            RetValue = InputBox(Prompt & "Enter Die Number")
            If RetValue = "" Then Exit Do ' optionally, to save two lines
        
            ' Remember that many of the VBA constants start with 'xl'
            ' that is lowercase 'XL', none with 'x1' that is lowercase 'X1'.
            Set cell = .Columns("C").Find(What:=RetValue, _
                 After:=.Range("C1"), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                 SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                 MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
            ' Note that with this setup the Find method will search
            ' in the following order: C2, C3,... CLastRow, C1.
            ' To make it search in the order C1...CLastRow, you could
            ' use 'After:=.Columns("C").Cells(.Columns("C").Rows.Count)',
            ' referencing the last cell in the column.
            ' Note that the last four arguments could be omitted:
            ' 1.) when the range is a single column or a single row,
            ' the 'SearchOrder' is irrelevant.
            ' 2.) 'SearchDirection' is by default 'xlNext'.
            ' 3.) 'MatchCase' is by default 'False'.
            ' 4.) 'SearchFormat' is rarely used. It uses 'True' to work
            ' with 'Application.FindFormat'. When you'll need it,
            ' you'll learn how to use it.
            
            ' You can format the output more appropriately (nicely).
            
            If cell Is Nothing Then
                MsgBox RetValue & " not found.", vbExclamation
            Else
                ' To reference the cell in the same row but in column 'A',
                ' you could use one of the following:
                ' 'cell.EntireRow.Columns("A")'
                ' '.Cells(cell.row, "A")'
                Bin = CStr(cell.EntireRow.Columns("A").Value)
                MsgBox RetValue & " in Bin " & Bin & ".", vbInformation
            End If
            'Prompt = Prompt ' is redundant; it's already 'Prompt'
            
        Loop
    
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the insight, I'm quite new to VB and your explanations were very useful.